# Android: Google playstore's open beta testing

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing

Recently learned of Google's latest testing services. That is `Closed Beta testing` and `Open Beta testing` from this link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213
and http://readwrite.com/2015/07/30/google-beta-test-tools.

Inorder to try the open beta testing feature of the same i have done the following:

1. Uploaded new APK for beta testing
2. Set the feed back email ID
3. Set the max number of testers.
4. get the `Opt-in URL` (after doing this i do not find any save button or anything as specified in the documentation.
5. Circulate this Opt-in URL among the testers.

**Below are the issue i'm facing:**

1. When i click on the opt-in URL via my Android device, First it asks me to have logged in. But since i'm trying out the Open beta testing which is not confined to a specific set of Emails (gmails) and any Google+ group or any Google Community, why is it taking me to the google login page?
2. After i login through my personal  mail Id, I get the below error message:
   [image: Error Message]

Has any one faced any such issue before? I'm i doing something wrong here?

Any infor regarding same shall be really helpful to any one who wants to try the new beta testing service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to set the number of testers if you don't want to. And the save button is labeled *Submit* and hidden in the top right corner.

Regarding your questions:

1. The open beta still works in conjunction with the play market. For example, it will push new beta updates if you have the app installed on your device.
2. I had a chat with the Google Developer Console support. Here is the answer, which worked for me. I waited ~2 hours before trying again:

> The reason you're getting this rather vague message is because the Beta (Version 145) was just published 17 minutes ago.
>
> It's still in the process of being published. Once it's fully published, that message should go away and you should be "eligible" to install the Beta.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the Save/Submit button anywhere until you told me to look in the top right corner. Way to go Google UI team...